# Keyboard shortcut to create a new folder in "Save File" dialog

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, directory, dialog

In an ordinary Nautilus window, I can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>N</kbd> to create a new folder, but this shortcut doesn't work in the "Save File" dialog. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, save file from what application?

Comment: Google Chrome, for instance (`File > Save page as...`).

Comment: Different applications use different dialogue windows, there is no general way to change the behaviour. If possible at all, that is, without editing source and recompile.

Comment: Any update on this?